# Is it possible to determine the aws instance of my app using js/node aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I'm creating an app that automatically scales by launching/copying an instance. If the instance is duplicated. i want my js code to determine the launced instance. I'm using AWS JavaScript SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to get information about the EC2 instance your application is running on? If so, you can send a HTTP request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ from your Node.js application running on the EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval

Is there a reason why you are not using Auto Scaling Groups to scale your application? Might be easier than implemting the scaling on your own.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html

Comment: Hi Sir! thanks for answering! 

"Are you trying to get information about the EC2 instance your application is running on?" Yes, and specifically the instance id my app is currently using. I'm very new to AWS and currently studying it so I don't have much of an idea. 

to be precise, I have an app that has sub apps. each sub apps are stored in separate instances that connects to different twitter accounts (with firehose api). if an instance is full, i need to create a new instance that will connect to twitter api.

Comment: Sorry if i don't speak english very well! any way thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I already know how to get my instance id inside using nodejs

```
`request({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4'
} ,function(err, data){
    if(err){
        cb(err, null);
    }else{
        var public_ip = data.body;
        cb(null, public_ip);
    }
});`
```